# Org-mode adding statistic cookie to date-tree lines in capture

Tags: org-mode, org-capture, time-date

In this video(timestamped to relevant section), I see this guy's org file in a date-tree with the [/] statistic cookie next to each YYYY-MM-DD headline.

https://youtu.be/-2RXhPV_zgc?t=12m51s

I'd like to be able to do date-tree captures in a file that has those statistic cookies.  Even though I can't figure out how to get this automated in a capture template, I figured I could just add them manually when I'm not capturing and working on that file directly.  But the problem is that when I then do another capture, it doesn't recognize the YYYY-MM-DD line after I edit it to include the [/].